# Setting up a real time dashboard/visualization of an existing Kafka ETL pipeline using Docker containers

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, visualization, real-time, dashboard

I after advice, recommendations or suggestions for setting up a real time dashboard/visualization of an existing Dockerized ETL pipeline using Kafka. The ETL consists of the following:

Extraction Service - Producer/Subscriber

Transformation Service - Producer/Subscriber

Load Service - Producer/Subscriber

Orchestration Service - Producer/Subscriber

Reporting Service - Subscriber

confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka

confluentinc/cp-zookeeper

provectuslabs/kafka-ui

All of these are Docker containers and are spun up together. I now need to be able to visualize the workflow of data through this process and I am not entirely sure where I should start of what would be the best approach.

So requirements are:

1. Visualization must be in real time
2. Visualization must be read only
3. No user interaction required to update the page data
4. Must be open source software

So I need to be able to query Topics and Topic Messages to get the data to display and also need someway of storing/tracking progress so I am guessing that I will some persistence mechanism or database to write to?

I have tried searching here and Googling elsewhere but it just adds to my confusion as I dont know where to start or what the most appropriate stack I should be looking at using.

I have heard mention that Kafka has a Stream-API would be something that that would be helpful to me?

For the realtime updates I need to use some sort of push notification, either Websockets or SignalR?

Does anyone know of any GIT repo's or tutorial sites they could point me to give me a foot up?

I am not looking for anybody to give me a ready made solution as I want to do the work myself but I could really just do with a shove in the right direction or a kick-start project if such a thing exists?

Comment: Try Kibana and the Elasticsearch sink connector. It's very flexible. https://www.confluent.io/blog/real-time-asset-tracking-software-with-kafka-elasticsearch-kibana/ + https://www.confluent.io/blog/streaming-etl-and-analytics-for-real-time-location-tracking/

Comment: Thank you, this has certainly helped give me a kickstart.